# Координаты метки из Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли как-то с помощью Google Maps Api получить координаты в форму? Например, у меня есть какой-то фрейм с картой, я там ставлю метку, а в мою форму передаются координаты той метки?

Есть код из старого моего проекта. Но тут я ввожу точку А и Б, и между ними рисуется путь, тут я могу вытащить lng и lat. Но могу ли я узнать координаты не вводя точку, и просто передвигать метку на карте?

```
function GetMap($inCity, $outCity) {
    echo '<center> <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin='.$outCity.'&destination='.$inCity.'&key=ХХХ_CEjbAbKb0Lfqjlk" allowfullscreen></iframe> </center>';
}

$request_params = array('origin' => $out ->street,
                    'destination'=> $in ->street,
                    'key'=>'ХХХ_HHpeZGjfgPpsFTBVPHXu4'
                    );
    $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
    $str = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?'.$get_params));

    foreach ($str->routes[0]->legs[0]->steps as $item) {
    $item->end_location->lng; // узнаем lng
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который у вас уже есть.

Comment: Это применено в инструменте Latitude and Longitude of a Point http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Рабочий пример внизу.

```js
function updateCoordinates(lat, lng) {
  document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
  document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
}

function initMap() {
  var map, marker;
  var myLatlng = {
    lat: 55.74,
    lng: 37.63
  };
  document.getElementById('lat').value = myLatlng.lat;
  document.getElementById('lng').value = myLatlng.lng;

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  marker.addListener('dragend', function(e) {
    var position = marker.getPosition();
    updateCoordinates(position.lat(), position.lng())
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
    updateCoordinates(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng())
  });

  map.panTo(myLatlng);
}
```

```css
#map {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="coordinates">
  Click somewhere on the map. Drag the marker to update the coordinates.
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    lat
    <input type="text" id="lat"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    lng
    <input type="text" id="lng"/>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbz9SsxmvvV-mXRkRGTH8F4cENndiecOk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Пример на
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/L68vqzgk/50/)

Answer (score 4):

Не использовал google API (больше по душе osm и leaflet), но в документации встречается следующая информация:

> События пользовательского интерфейса в Google Maps JavaScript API
>   обычно передают свой аргумент, который может быть получен блоком
>   прослушивания событий. Этот аргумент сообщает состояние
>   пользовательского интерфейса на момент события. Например, событие
>   'click' пользовательского интерфейса обычно передает событие
>   MouseEvent со свойством latLng, обозначающее точку нажатия на карте.
>   Такое поведение характерно только для событий пользовательского
>   интерфейса, при событиях изменения состояния MVC аргументы не
>   передаются.

Следовательно, координаты точки, в которой был совершен клик, можно получить с помощью прослушивания события click на карте:

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latLng);
    /* do something */
  });
```

В общем, надо смотреть в сторону прослушивания событий. Ну и если речь про метку и отслеживание ее перемещений, можно создать перемещаемый маркер (в latLng - какие-нибудь координаты)

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latLng, 
  map:map,
  draggable:true
);
```

и повесить на него обработчик событий. Если интересна конечная точка - событие dragend (когда перемещение маркера закончится):

```
marker.addListener('dragend', function(e) {
  console.log(e.latLng);
  /* do something */
});
```

Ну и получить непосредственно lat и lng можно, заменив e.latLng на

```
e.latLng.lat();
e.latLng.lng();
```